# File Upload and Database design in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

In my project, I have users table and I want to store uploaded files of each user.
My Database approach- Instead of storing the files per user directly in row per user, I want the following design:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|  user_id  |  user_name  |  folder_path |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|  U123     |  Sherlock   |  xyzdsalfb   |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

here each user row in database would contain link/path to dedicated folder/repo for each user so that only that user could access it using login.
Then I need to display the files uploaded by user in a list on user dashboard page.

Current Database design is:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id'); //we need enroll number too
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('enroll_no')->unique(); //we'll change this to bigInteger
            $table->string('course');
            $table->string('majors');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

How to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new migration to add columns to your table. [Per the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations) first run:

```
php artisan make:migration add_your_columns_to_users_table --table=users
```

That'll generate your migration. You'll want to check out the Laravel docs for adding columns to a database using a migration to add the correct columns:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns

A quick example adding a column for `folder_path` would be:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('folder_path');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('folder_path');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as adding columns is concerned, I know how to do that. What I need is some code for file uploading.i.e. how it is handled in controllers,what methods need to be made and how to get the list of files uploaded by a user. Btw, very good explanation of adding columns. Thanks for that. If you could help ahead, it would be appreciating.

Comment: Ah ok. You're going to need to make your question clearer, it doesn't ask that at the moment.

Comment: Simply, I want a tutorial showing file upload code and how the files get stored and how to get their url in database for further access like enlisting all the files of a user on his dashboard. e.g. Google Drive-which enlists all files for the respective user along with download etc options .Secondly, what would be better approach- 1)Creating folder for each user 2) Storing files of all users in common place. In either case, how to identify which file belongs to which user.

Comment: You'll want to hit Google for tutorials really dude.